# Set header on a formData Angular

Tags: node.js, angularjs, http, multipartform-data

I have a problem when I try to send a file via http with FormData () in Angular. The headers that I get to the java code are not correct, how can I go about correcting this?

[When I send request with Postman:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5jkj.png)

[When I send request with frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbcnD.png)

Comment: Post the Angular code showing how you do the HTTP POST

Comment: Avoid putting essential information for your question as images, or, at least add a small descriptions (just in case the image hosting expires).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.